# Style is not applied to css combinators + pseudo classes with makeStyles() material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### Current Behavior

Passing props to makeStyles() doesn't work for `CSS combinators`

### Expected Behavior

Should work with `CSS combinators`

### Steps to Reproduce

Steps:

1. Create style props

```
export interface StyleProps {
    width: string;   //Tried number but same
}
```

2. Pass props to makeStyle()

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, StyleProps>((theme) => ({
   card: {
        //Some other styles ...
        '&:hover $filledBar': props => ({
            width: props.width,    //This doesn't work
            transition: '0.4s ease-out'
        })
   },
   filledBar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0rem',
        zIndex: 3,
        width: '0rem',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,154,217,1) 0%, rgba(217,147,0,1) 65%, rgba(255,186,0,1) 100%)',
        transition: '0.6s ease-out',
    },
}));
```

3. Pass Props

```
    const styleProps: StyleProps = { width: '12rem' }    //Tried number but same
    const classes = useStyles(styleProps);
```

### Environment

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

- Material-UI | v4.11.0
- React       | v16.13.1
- Browser     |  Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- TypeScript  |  3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it like this:

````
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   card: (props: StyleProps) => ({
        //Some other styles ...
        '&:hover $filledBar': {
            width: props.width, 
            transition: '0.4s ease-out'
        }
   }),
   filledBar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0rem',
        zIndex: 3,
        width: '0rem',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,154,217,1) 0%, rgba(217,147,0,1) 65%, rgba(255,186,0,1) 100%)',
        transition: '0.6s ease-out',
    },
}));```
````